# Can you write a Google Sheets function that draws something?

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to write your own custom function in google sheets script that returns a drawn image, similar to how the SPARKLINE function works, except I want to make one that draws a pie chart instead.

I do **not** want to use Insert > Chart... > Pie Chart because that creates a floating chart on top of the spreadsheet. I would like to be able to write my own function that would return a pie chart that is embedded within the cell that the function is entered in, just like you can do with columns, bars, and line charts using sparkline.

Answer (score 3):

How about following idea? This sample script embeds a chart to a cell using custom function on Spreadsheet. I think that this method is one of various ideas.

### Problems :

When you want to create a chart and embed it to a cell using custom functions, you notice that `insertChart()` cannot be used. There are some limitations for using custom functions. But `insertChart()` creates floating charts. So in order to embed a chart to a cell, the function `=IMAGE()` is suitable for this situation. Here, `setFormula()` for setting `=IMAGE()` and `DriveApp.createFile()` for creating images from charts also cannot be used for custom functions.

### Solution :

In order to avoid these limitations, I used [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

To use this sample script, please deploy Web Apps as follows.

On the Script Editor,

- File

  - -> Manage Versions
  - -> Save New Version
- Publish

  - -> Deploy as Web App
  - -> At Execute the app as, select **"your account"**
  - -> At Who has access to the app, select **"Anyone, even anonymous"**
  - -> Click **"Deploy"**
  - -> Copy **"Current web app URL"**
  - -> Click **"OK"**

When it deploys Web Apps, the approval required authorization can be done, simultaneously.

### Sample Script :

Please copy and paste this script to a bound script of spreadsheet.

```
var folderId = "### Folder ID ###"; // This is a folder to save images.
var webappsurl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/######/exec"; // Here, please put "Current web app URL".

function embedChart(range) {
  var ac = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var q1 = "?datarange=" + range;
  var q2 = "&row=" + ac.getRow();
  var q3 = "&col=" + ac.getColumn();
  var url = webappsurl + q1 + q2 + q3;
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}

function doGet(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.PIE)
    .addRange(sheet.getRange(e.parameters.datarange))
    .setOption('height', 280)
    .setOption('width', 480)
    .setOption('title', 'Sample chart')
    .build();
  var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(
    chart.getAs('image/png').setName("chart_image.png")
  );
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  sheet.getRange(e.parameters.row, e.parameters.col).setFormula(
    '=IMAGE("' + "http://drive.google.com/uc?id=" + file.getId() + '")'
  );
}
```

#### Flow of Script :

**embedChart()**

1. Input `=embedChart("a2:a6")` in cell `B7`.
2. Using `fetch()`, sends data of `a2:a6` and the inputted coordinate to `doGet()`.

**doGet()**

1. Using `doGet()`, get the data.
2. Creates a chart using inputted range `a2:a6`. (in this case, creates a pie chart)
3. Saves a chart as an image.  (in this case, saves as PNG)
4. Updates a permission of the image file to use for `=IMAGE()`.
5. Embeds the image using `=IMAGE()` which was imported by `setFormula()`.

### Result :

By inputting `=embedChart("a2:a6")` in cell `B7` as a custom function, following result can be obtained.

[image]

### Note :

1. When the custom function `embedChart()` is used, loading time is about 40 seconds. (I don't know whether this occurs at only my environment.)
2. Permissions of the created image are [ANYONE_WITH_LINK](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access), [VIEW](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission).
3. `embedChart()` is overwritten by `=IMAGE()`. So when the spreadsheet is reopened, the response of `=IMAGE()` is much faster than that of `embedChart()`.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: That is a cool workaround, but I was wondering if it was possible to write a script that does something like like create a canvas, draw on it, and return it to the cell.

Comment: From previous experiences, I had known that Web Apps can avoid various limitations on Google Apps Script, while it requires the authorization at first run. So I tried it for this situation. Did this work on your environment? If this will be helpful for you, I'm glad.