# Using triggers with custom functions on Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had a prob with my script, which was greatly answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64895519/required-permissions-https-www-googleapis-com-auth-spreadsheets#64896152).
Basically custom functions cannot call services that require authorization. However, as far as I understood if I use simple triggers, such as onEdit it could work.

I checked the documentation suggested in the previous question, however I wasn't successful applying that to my code, which you can see below:

```
function FileName (id) {
  var ss = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  return ss.getName();
}
```

How could I adapt my code to use simple triggers?

[Here is a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/120xSaw_JFBcptu_rEoiX2H5lMKsBaHZmTcMX846Q_vg/edit#gid=0) that replicates the problem.

Comment: Simple triggers can't  call services that requires permission either. You'd need to use installable triggers => getValues (all ids) and setValues (all file names). Review best practices and JavaScript  arrays. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Could you provide a suggestion using installable triggers?

Comment: I cannot understand about `Using simple triggers with custom functions on Google Apps Script`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By the way, from your sample Spreadsheet, I thought that you might want to use your function of `FileName` as the custom function of Google Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike my goal is to get the name of the files everytime a new URL is registered in the spreadsheet. Regarding the function FileName, well it would be good to use a custom function however it is not possible with services that require authorization.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a workaround for achieving your goal. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to use your function of `FileName` as the custom function of Google Spreadsheet.

  - You want to automatically retrieve the filename when the file ID is put to the column "B".
  - You want to put the filename to the column "C".

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, when the custom function is used, in the current specification, the most methods except several methods (for example, one of them is UrlFetchApp.) that the authorization is required cannot be used. By this, `DriveApp.getFileById(id)` in your script cannot be used with the custom function. But there is a workaround. At the custom function, UrlFetchApp can be used. In this answer, I would like to propose to use the Web Apps with UrlFetchApp as the wrapper for authorizing. By this, the authorization can be done with the Web Apps. So your function can be run by the custom function.

### Usage:

#### 1. Prepare script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and save it.

```
const key = "samplekey"; // This is a key for using Web Apps. You can freely modify this.

// This is your function.
function FileName_(id) {
  var ss = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  return ss.getName();
}

// Web Apps using as the wrapper for authorizing.
function doGet(e) {
  let res = "";
  if (e.parameter.key === key) {
    try {
      res = FileName_(e.parameter.id);
    } catch (err) {
      res = `Error: ${err.message}`;
    }
  } else {
    res = "Key error.";
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({value: res}));
}

function Filename(id) {
  const webAppsUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"; // Please set the URL of Web Apps after you set the Web Apps.

  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`${webAppsUrl}?id=${id}&key=${key}`);
  if (res.getResponseCode() != 200) throw new Error(res.getContentText());
  return JSON.parse(res.getContentText()).value;
}
```

#### 2. Deploy Web Apps.

1. On the script editor, Open a dialog box by "Publish" -> "Deploy as web app".
2. Select **"Me"** for **"Execute the app as:"**.

   - By this, the script is run as the owner.
3. Select **"Anyone, even anonymous"** for **"Who has access to the app:"**.

   - In this case, the access token is not required to request to Web Apps. But in this sample script, a key for requesting to Web Apps is used.
4. Click "Deploy" button as new "Project version".
5. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

   1. Click "Review Permissions".
   2. Select own account.
   3. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
   4. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
   5. Click "Allow" button.
6. Click "OK".
7. Copy the URL of Web Apps. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
8. Please set the URL of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec` to url of above script. And please redeploy Web Apps. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. So please be careful this.

#### 3. Test this workaround.

When the file ID is put to the cell "A1", please put `=filename(A1)` to a cell as the custom function. By this, the script is run and the response value is returned.

#### Note:

- Above sample script is a simple sample script for testing your script. So when you want to use the various methods, this post might be useful.
- Please use this script with enabling V8.
- As other method, I think that when the file ID is manually put to the column "B", the installable OnEdit trigger can be used. The sample script is as follows. Please set the sheet name. And please install the trigger to the function of `installedOnEdit`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) By this, when the file ID is put to the column "B" of `sheetName`, the file ID is put to the column "C".

  ```
    function installedOnEdit(e) {
      const sheetName = "Sheet1";
      const range = e.range;
      const sheet = range.getSheet();
      if (!(sheet.getSheetName() == sheetName && range.getColumn() == 2 && range.getRow() > 1)) return;
      const value = range.getValue();
      let res = "";
      try {
        res = DriveApp.getFileById(value).getName();
      } catch(e) {
        res = e.message;
      }
      range.offset(0, 1).setValue(res);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)
- [Enhanced Custom Function for Google Spreadsheet using Web Apps as Wrapper](https://github.com/tanaikech/Enhanced-Custom-Function-for-Google-Spreadsheet-using-Web-Apps-as-Wrapper)
- Related questions

  - [Can you write a Google Sheets function that draws something?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44182925)
  - [Error when running Youtube Data Service in App Scripts (js) – Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62205747)
  - [How to enable not authorized users to protect the spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64086095)
  - [Changing Owner of the Sheet irrespective of the duplicator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64666605)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, wonderful as always. I ended using the simpler solution, the one you've put in your Notes. For future reference, If I'd like to set the result to another column I just need to change the `range.offset(0,1)` to another offset, such as `range.offset(0,3)` for instance (it will move the result 3 columns forward).

Comment: I noticed that this solution only works when I change it manually, not when a formula changes the content of the cell. In this line of solution, is there a way to trigger when the cell changes automatically or only when I edit manually?

Comment: @abutremutante Thank you for replying. When you want to run the function when the formulas updates the cells, in this case, I think that it is required to use the time-driven trigger. Using the time-driven trigger, it checks the cells you want to update. But if this is not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I considered that as well but in my case the file could be deleted after a minute or less so I think the edit trigger would work better

Answer (score 1):

### As you can draw from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions), simple triggers cannot access services that require authorization neither

You have to use [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead.

However the workflow is very different from custom functions.

In your specific case, you can implement e.g. that when a cell in column A is being edited (that is a new URL is being inserted) - the respective file name is being found and returned into column D.

You can retrieve the value and the row in which the new URL is being inserted with help of [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

Sample:

```js
function FileName (event) {
  var id = event.value;
  var ss = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  var row = event.range.getRow();
  var sheet = event.range.getSheet();
  // for column D:
  var column = 4;
  var returnCell = sheet.getRange(row,column);
  returnCell.setValue(ss.getName());
}
```

For using an installable `onEdit` trigger - bind it to this function through going on  `Edit > Current project's triggers` as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer. I did what you suggested, you can see in the sample file. Edited current project triggers as explained, used this very same code and I'm still getting "Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) (line 8).". Line 8 is the following:   var ss = DriveApp.getFileById(id); Did you manage to make it work? Could you share the file?

Comment: The code as it is works if you bind it to an installable `onEdit` trigger. But opposed to custom functions you cannot type into a cell sometihng like `=FileName(A1)`, neither can you run the code manually from the script editor - it runs automatically when you add or modify a value in column An installable trigger runs under authorization of the person who created it and is only visible by this person. If I install a trigger to your funciton, I won't be authorized to access files on your Drive - so you are the one who has to bind an installable onEdit trigger to the function `FileName (event)`

Comment: Btw., if you do not want to apply the function to new URLs only, but to all URLs already present in the sheet, consider not using triggers, but instead setting up a manually to run function, that returns the file name for all present URLs at once. It can be run e.g. on [button click](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets).

Comment: Thanks for explaining I can't use `=FileName(A1)` as I was using. What would be the correct synthax? Or I don't even need to call the function and it should run automatically (it's not running by the way...)?

Comment: Yes, it should run automatically - providied you correctly installed the `onEdit` trigger. But a trigger fires on an event - in your case on adding a NEW URL into a cell in column A.