# Installable on Edit trigger that triggers on one cell, gets data from another and writes data in a third cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm using a function to collect file names of Google Drive URLs using onEdit installable trigger ([thanks to @Tanaike's suggestion in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64897709/using-triggers-with-custom-functions-on-google-apps-script/64907832?noredirect=1#comment114794430_64907832)):

```
function FileName(e) {
    const sheetName = "Página1";
    const range = e.range;
    const sheet = range.getSheet();
    if (!(sheet.getSheetName() == sheetName && range.getColumn() == 2 && range.getRow() > 1)) return;
    const value = range.getValue();
    let res = "";
    try {
      res = DriveApp.getFileById(value).getName();
    } catch(e) {
      res = e.message;
    }
    range.offset(0, 1).setValue(res);
  }
```

I need to find a way to adapt it and activate the trigger in the edition of a different cell, in this exemplified step-by-step:

a) I change C2 and it activates the trigger,

b) The function grabs the file ID in B2, identifies the file and puts it in D2.

[Here is a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oU-8JyAQpUZW-n5MbduofjC85s7pHoIXxq0X3EXh2V8/edit#gid=0)

**EDIT**

So, the question is:
This code above activates the trigger and gets file ID in the same cell B2. How do I make it activate the edit trigger in C2 and get file ID in B2?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Diego I included an edit. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

- I think your goal is to trigger this function on edits in column `C` and set the value in column `D` based on the value in column `B`.
- If you want to grab changes in column `C`, modify the column check in
  the `if` statement to this:

  `range.getColumn() == 3`
- But since you now want to get the value in column `B`, use:

  `const value = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(),range.getColumn()-1).getValue()`
- this line `range.offset(0, 1).setValue(res)` will set the value in column `D`.

**Solution:**

```
function FileName(e) {
    const sheetName = "Página1";
    const range = e.range;
    const sheet = range.getSheet();
    if (!(sheet.getSheetName() == sheetName && range.getColumn() == 3 && range.getRow() > 1)) return;
    const value = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(),range.getColumn()-1).getValue();

    let res = "";
    try {
      res = DriveApp.getFileById(value).getName();
    } catch(e) {
      res = e.message;
    }
    range.offset(0, 1).setValue(res);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Marios. I'm getting a "Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp." and the prob is not in the file neither in my settings because the previous code works (when I change column B it gets the name). The sample file is editable now, you can check deleting and re-pasting content on B and writting anything on C.

Comment: @abutremutante yes sorry, check my updated code. I can't run your code because these file IDs are files in your Google drive and as it makes sense Google wouldn't allow me to do that. But the updated code should work